# OnsenUI2.0で、タブ表示(ons-tabbar)した時のAngularJSのコントローラのふるまいについて

Tags: onsen-ui, angularjs

OnsenUIを1系から2.0への移行を検討しています。
angularJSは1.5を使用しています。

下記のons-tabで設定している各ページにコントローラを適用しています。
OnsenUI 1系では、それぞれのタブに割り当てられたページを開くと、それに対応するコントローラのJavascriptが実行されていましたが、
OnsenUI 2.0では、最初のページを開くと、すべてのページのコントローラのJavascriptが実行されているように思われます。(開いていないタブのページのコントローラも実行される)

OnsenUI 2.0でも、各タブを開いたときに、該当するコントローラのJavascriptが実行されるようにしたいのですが、できずに困っています。

解決する方法がありますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
<ons-tabbar>
  <ons-tab page="home.html" active="true">HOME</ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="fav.html">FAV</ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="settings.html">SETTINGS</ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>
```

Comment: [Ons-tabbar different controllers on each tab #1506](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/1506) 2.0ではすべてのタブがロードされるので、`ons-tabbar`のイベントで実行させるようなことが書いてありますね。

Comment: ありがとうございました。OnsenUI2.0の仕様なんですね。postchange eventを試してみます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ons-tab`の`page`属性に記述せずに、`ons-tabbar`の`loadPage()`メソッドを使用してページを読み込ませることで、似たような動作をさせることができます。
**※下記コードは、monacaの環境で確認した内容です。**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
        var app = ons.bootstrap("myApp", ["onsen"]);
        app.controller("indexController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
            ons.ready(function() {
                $scope.loadPage("page1.html");
            });
            $scope.loadPage = function(page) {
                myTabbar.loadPage(page);
            };
        }]);
        app.controller("page1Controller", ["$scope", function($scope) {
            ons.ready(function() {
        console.log("load page1");
            });
        }]);
        app.controller("page2Controller", ["$scope", function($scope) {
            ons.ready(function() {
        console.log("load page2");
            });
        }]);
        app.controller("page3Controller", ["$scope", function($scope) {
            ons.ready(function() {
        console.log("load page3");
            });
        }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="indexController">
    <ons-tabbar var="myTabbar">
        <ons-tab label="Page 1" icon="ion-home" ng-click="loadPage('page1.html')" active="true"></ons-tab>
        <ons-tab label="Page 2" icon="ion-earth" ng-click="loadPage('page2.html')"></ons-tab>
        <ons-tab label="Page 3" icon="ion-android-options" ng-click="loadPage('page3.html')"></ons-tab>
    </ons-tabbar>

    <ons-template id="page1.html">
        <ons-page ng-controller="page1Controller">
            <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="center">Page 1</div>
            </ons-toolbar>
            Page 1
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="page2.html">
        <ons-page ng-controller="page2Controller">
            <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="center">Page 2</div>
            </ons-toolbar>
            Page 2
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="page3.html">
        <ons-page ng-controller="page3Controller">
            <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="center">Page 3</div>
            </ons-toolbar>
            Page 3
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 上記のように回答しましたが、`Onsen UI v2.0.5`で使用すると`The loadPage method has been deprecated and will be removed in the next minor version.`というメッセージが表示されるので、最新版では注意が必要です。